# XNA:Rectangles Movement Behavior

Tags: xna, c#

im trying to create simple pong game, and learning some XNA.
im creating for each paddle 3 rectangles, who represnt the collision when the ball hit them, so i can dicide where to throw the ball back.

here is the function that i create the rectangles:

```
List<Rectangle> collisonRectanglesList = new List<Rectangle>(3);
      private void creatCollisonRectangles()
        {
 smallPaddleWidth = collisionRect.Width;
             smallPaddleHeight = collisionRect.Height / 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < collisonRectanglesList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (collisonRectanglesList[i] != null)
                    collisonRectanglesList.RemoveAt(i);
            }    
             collisonRectanglesList.Add(new Rectangle((int)position.X + smallPaddleWidth, (int)position.Y + smallPaddleHeight * 2, smallPaddleWidth, smallPaddleHeight));
             collisonRectanglesList.Add(new Rectangle((int)position.X + smallPaddleWidth, (int)position.Y + smallPaddleHeight, smallPaddleWidth, smallPaddleHeight));
             collisonRectanglesList.Add(new Rectangle((int)position.X + smallPaddleWidth, (int)position.Y , smallPaddleWidth, smallPaddleHeight));
            
        }
```

now i want this to follow the paddle it self so i put this function in the update method
and made a simple texture so i can draw them and see where they are on the screen.

my problem is that when i call the `creatCollisonRectangles()` 1 of the rectangles paint it self in the middle and not in the place it should be.

any idea why?

this is when im not calling it in the Update method:
[image: this is when im not calling the function in the update methodand how it should be]

and this when i do:
[image: this is when i do CALL the function and try to see if it move with the paddle]

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Just trying to make sure I understand: you're generating the collision rectangles on every update? Why not create them once then update the positions?

Comment: i just tried that and i get an error:Error 1 Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle>.this[int]' so i have to create the rectangle every time i guess.

Comment: i read a litell about the error and use your suggustion and i just changed the List<Rectangle> to an arry and just update the position  like you said and it solved my problem! i realy want to give you right answer :)

Comment: Now you can ;) I'm glad that worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're generating new collision rectangles every update and this probably means that you're a) overriding the rectangle you mean to draw or b) trying to access a rectangle which no longer exists. Creating the rectangles once then updating their positions would fix that (not to mention be much more efficient that allocating new rectangles every fraction of a second ;) ).